# Microsoft office 365 Groups: Guest user are unable to do drive call using graph endpoint

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Our application reads group drive content by doing Get call on the drive item. This used to work fine for both internal members and guest users. Its working now for internal members but not working anymore for guest users. Following is the sample call.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!uey_5Lpf8Eu0-5HlGvJvFga89s_hTxNAg9kSsTlOBqajRqOF3ec-Rp6uqtbLNt4w/items/016GMDDVB74LSDDYRHHRHJ5KV5HHVXWQTT?$select=webUrl,name

The response we get is this

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "unauthenticated",
    "message": "Role Claim does not exist for Service Asserted App V1.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "5ed31bd5-283c-4ce2-a6d6-a249f94ae9ee",
        "date": "2018-06-27T09:39:01"
    }
}
```

This used to work fine previously, Is something changed recently with Drive API?
I have checked the changed logs but nothing is mentioned regarding this in the last release.

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059669/exceptions-in-calls-to-onedrive-graph-api @Marc Lafleur

Answer (score 1):

This is now resolved by Graph Team and works fine now.