# Exceptions in calls to OneDrive graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Today we started to get exceptions in a previously normally working solution like the below from the Graph API calls to v1 endpoints of group's "OneDrive" (GET /v1.0/groups/xxxxx/drive/root:/.)

"   Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: unauthenticated.  Message: Role Claim does not exist for Service Asserted App V1.
  Inner error at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider."

Any clues where to look at for troubleshooting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Please include a minimum viable sample showing the code you're using. Ideally include the HTTP trace using a tool like Fiddler.

Comment: This issue is also reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059599/microsoft-office-365-groups-guest-user-are-unable-to-do-drive-call-using-graph Cyril.