# Guest users get unauthenticated when calling OneDrive through the graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Today Guest users in Groups started getting unauthenticated errors when calling OneDrive objects through the Microsoft Graph. I see others are reporting the same in other posts. @marc-lafleur

Request:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!Sd7PJstOMUyRktUqCP0SCiuiFPse_zxDrRCufOLLTLvOTGuwXirNSpqvcJtm9YaO/items/0173HJLOWFCUJDCTLMB5HJOBFF44YF3L5Q/children?$select=id,name,folder,webUrl,lastModifiedDateTime,size,createdBy,createdDateTime

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "unauthenticated",
    "message": "Role Claim does not exist for Service Asserted App V1.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "e059ddf5-32b7-4c9c-b849-9ea0d223a96e",
      "date": "2018-06-27T12:54:55"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We are facing the same issue, this worked fine till 25th June but not working since yesterday.

Comment: This issue is also reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059599/microsoft-office-365-groups-guest-user-are-unable-to-do-drive-call-using-graph Cyril.

Comment: As per the other thread on this from June '18, this issue has been resolved by the Microsoft Graph team. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059599/microsoft-office-365-groups-guest-user-are-unable-to-do-drive-call-using-graph